# Getting template_include to work when allow_url_include is off?

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, templates, php.ini

I'm working on a plugin that creates a custom post type and I would like to display a custom template without modifying the theme.

Here's the simplified code I'm working with:

```
add_filter('template_include', 'my_custom_template');

function my_custom_template($incFile) {
    global $wp;
    global $wp_query;

    if ($wp->query_vars['post_type'] == 'custom-post-type') {

        $incFile = MY_PLUGIN_TEMPLATES . '/template.php';

    }

    return $incFile;

}
```

The problem I'm running into is that when allow_url_include is turned off in a server's php.ini file, this throws a fun little error:

**Warning:** include() [function.include]: http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_include=0 in http://path\to\wp-includes\template-loader.php on line 43

So I guess the question is, is there a way to send a template through the template_include filter without triggering this allow_url_include error?

Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't ya know - 10 minutes or less since I asked my question and I've discovered the answer.  

I was attempting to define MY_PLUGIN_TEMPLATES using plugins_dir_url(), now it looks like this:

    `define( 'MY_PLUGIN_TEMPLATES', WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/my_plugin/templates' );`

And all is well.

Comment: I always set the plugin path using the following code: `dirname( __FILE__ )` - It will allow the name of the plugin directory to be changed without modifying the code.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't ya know - 10 minutes or less since I asked my question and I've discovered the answer.

I was attempting to define MY_PLUGIN_TEMPLATES using using plugins_dir_url(), now it looks like this and is working:

```
define( 'MY_PLUGIN_TEMPLATES', dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/templates' );
```

Thanks to mfields for the suggestion of dirname instead of WP_PLUGIN_DIR.